# ngFor isn't working on <tr> element

Tags: javascript, angular

So I'm working on a forum in my MEAN-stack app and I requested the sections from my node.js back-end. I was able to receive what I want from the back-end, but when I want to display the 4 sections I retrieved I am unable to make the rows appear on my screen. I did the same mechanism on my sub-forums and it does seem to work there, but I don't see what's making this not work.

**My forum template (forum.component.html)**

```
<div class="row justify-content-center mb-3 mt-5">
    <div class="col-md-8">
        <table class="table">
            <thead>
            <tr>
                <th>Forum</th>
                <th>Posts</th>
                <th>Replies</th>
                <th>Last Post</th>
            </tr>
            </thead>
            <tbody>
            <tr *ngFor="let section of sections" [routerLink]="section.name">
                <td>
                    <p><b>{{section.name}}</b></p>
                    <p>For all general topics of Wizards Unite.<br> Ask a question or open a topic te contribute to the community.</p>
                </td>
                <td>{{section.posts.length}}</td>
                <td>{{section.totalReplies}}</td>
                <td>
                    <p>{{section.lastPost.title}}</p>
                    <p>by {{section.lastPost.name}} on {{section.lastPost.date | amDateFormat:'LL'}}</p>
                </td>
            </tr>
            </tbody>
        </table>
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-2 side-column">

    </div>
</div>
```

**my forum component (forum.component.ts)**

```
import {Component, OnInit} from "@angular/core";
import {ForumService} from "./forum.service";
import {ActivatedRoute} from "@angular/router";

@Component({
    selector: 'forum',
    templateUrl: 'forum.component.html',
    styleUrls: [
        'forum.component.css'
    ]
})

export class ForumComponent implements OnInit {

    sections = [];

    constructor(private forumService: ForumService, private route: ActivatedRoute){}

    ngOnInit(){

            this.forumService.getSections()
                .subscribe(function (sections:any) {
                    this.sections = sections.obj;
                    console.log(this.sections);
                })

    }
}
```

**Here is the data that I received from the getSections() function in my component. On first sight everything is as I desire, but as you can see the rows do not appear on the left side of the screen ***

[image]

Comment: Are you sure that `this.sections = sections.obj;` is correct? Not `this.sections = sections`?

Comment: What's in the console

Comment: @FrankModica Yeah there doesn't seem to be any existing `sections.obj` in the response

Comment: I did a console.log of this.sections and the result you see on the right side of the screenshot. It show an array of 4 section objects.

Comment: Sorry I misread

Comment: Do you have the [CommonModule](https://angular.io/api/common/CommonModule) imported?

Comment: try `this.sections = Object.values(sections)`

Comment: Have you tried inspecting the DOM to see if it's just a display issue?

Comment: Sam, you mean in app.module? I haven't, but I did now and it's still not showing

Comment: Vikas, tried it, still not showing

Comment: `this.sections = sections`

Comment: user 184994, I'll take a screenshot of the DOM and add it.

Comment: Is you app using "ChangeDetectionStrategy"?

Comment: Hang on, change `function (sections:any)` to `(sections:any) =>`, because the context of `this` is being lost. By using an arrow function, it should retain its context

Comment: Provide a stackblitz

Comment: Peineary, the object I sent back from node.js has the structure {message:... , obj:...}

Comment: Thanks user184994, it was indeed the context that was lost by forgetting to use an arrow function. Thank a lot!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When a callback function is invoked, often the context of `this` will change.

In your example, `this` is no longer referring to the class, so it's not setting the `sections` as you're expecting.

Change `function (sections:any)` to `(sections:any) =>`. By using an arrow function, it should retain its context